# Items with LoadMore Button, filter and the detail of first item or clicked item in React hooks

Tags: javascript, react.js

I am building the list of items (TEST) with `loadMore` button with filter  and want to have loading state in LoadMore button and items itself.

After loading the item I will fetch the detail of the first item for the first time and after that load the detail of the test.

This code does not contain the fetching of the detail.

If the item is clicked again load the detail of another test.

````
function TeacherTest() {
  let { moduleId, url } = useModuleContext();
  const [tests, setTests] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [activeTestId, setActiveTestId] = useState(null);
  const [limit, setLimit] = useState(1);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
  const [moreTest, setMoreTest] = useState(true);
  const [loadingMore, setLoadingMore] = useState(false);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("all");

  const fetchTests = () => {
    console.log(offset, "offset  fetchTest");
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `${url}/teacher/test?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`,
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then((res) => {
      let newTests = res.data.tests;
      newTests.length < limit && setMoreTest(false);
      console.log(newTests === []);
      console.log(newTests);
      tests ? setTests([...tests, ...newTests]) : setTests(newTests);
    });
  };

  useMemo(() => {
    setTests(null);
    setOffset(0);
  }, [filter])

  const showMoreTest = () => {
    setOffset(offset + limit);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTests();
  }, [url, offset, filter]);

  return (
    <div className="w-100" id="dash__wrapper">
      <div className="dashboard__container mt-4">
        <div className="main_dash">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4 col-12 mb-2 px-0">
              <div className="pt-0">
                <div className="btn btn-block p-0 my-0">
                  <form action="./quiz-setup.php">
                    <Link to={`/${moduleId}/teacher/test/add`}>
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-lightblue p-2 w-100 mb-2"
                        id="addTest"
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-plus pr-1" />
                        Add New Test
                      </button>
                    </Link>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <TestSchedule
                tests={tests}
                moreTest={moreTest}
                filter={filter}
                setFilter={setFilter}
                showMoreTest={showMoreTest}
                loadingMore={loadingMore}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-8">
              <TestDetail />
              <TestResult />
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-4 col-12 mb-2 pl-md-2 px-0"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

```
function TestSchedule({ tests, showMoreTest, setFilter, loadingMore, moreTest }) {
  return (
    <div className="bg-white p-3 chart_contain dash__shadow dash__border">
      <div className="w-100 clearfix mb-2">
        <h6 className="py-2" style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
          Test Schedule
        </h6>
        <div className="float-right">
          {/* Dropdown to select test logs */}
          <form>
            <select
              defaultValue="all"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setFilter(e.target.value);
              }}
              className="custom-select border-0"
            >
              <option value="all">All</option>
              <option value="active">Active</option>
              <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
              <option value="completed">Completed</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="bg-light radius-10 p-2 mb-1">
        <p className="quest__name">Weekly test 12</p>
        <ul className="list-inline description-ans text-muted">
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="far fa-clock" />
            &nbsp;40 min
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-bullseye" />
            &nbsp;80 Marks
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-desktop" />
            &nbsp;40 Questions
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-users" />
            &nbsp;MBBS 1st Year
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="row control-question d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div>
            <span className="badge badge-pill badge-success">Active</span>
            <small className="text-muted">June 20, 2020 - 17:00 NPT</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="major__btn test-log">
              <a href="#">
                <button className="major__btn__type button__blue p-0 m-0">
                  <i className="fas fa-edit" />
                </button>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <button className="major__btn__type button__red p-0 m-0 ml-2">
                  <i className="fas fa-trash" />
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="bg-light radius-10 p-2 mb-1">
        <p className="quest__name">Weekly test 12</p>
        <ul className="list-inline description-ans text-muted">
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="far fa-clock" />
            &nbsp;40 min
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-bullseye" />
            &nbsp;80 Marks
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-desktop" />
            &nbsp;40 Questions
          </li>
          <li className="list-inline-item">
            <i className="fas fa-users" />
            &nbsp;MBBS 1st Year
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="row control-question d-flex justify-content-between">
          <div>
            <span className="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Expired on</span>
            <small className="text-muted">June 20, 2020 - 17:00 NPT</small>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="major__btn test-log">
              <a href="#">
                <button className="major__btn__type button__blue p-0 m-0">
                  <i className="fas fa-edit" />
                </button>
              </a>
              <a href="#">
                <button className="major__btn__type button__red p-0 m-0 ml-2">
                  <i className="fas fa-trash" />
                </button>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      {tests ?
        tests.map((t, index) => {
          // console.log(t, "From single test");
          let { duration, id, end, name } = t;
          return (
            <div key={index} className="bg-light radius-10 p-2 mb-1">
              <p className="quest__name">{name}</p>
              <ul className="list-inline description-ans text-muted">
                <li className="list-inline-item">
                  <i className="far fa-clock" />
                  &nbsp;{duration} min
                </li>
                <li className="list-inline-item">
                  <i className="fas fa-bullseye" />
                  &nbsp;80 Marks
                </li>
                <li className="list-inline-item">
                  <i className="fas fa-desktop" />
                  &nbsp;40 Questions
                </li>
                <li className="list-inline-item">
                  <i className="fas fa-users" />
                  &nbsp;MBBS 1st Year
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div className="row control-question d-flex justify-content-between">
                <div>
                  <span className="badge badge-pill badge-info">
                    Scheduled for
                  </span>
                  <small className="text-muted">
                    June 20, 2020 - 17:00 NPT
                  </small>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div className="major__btn test-log">
                    <a href="#">
                      <button className="major__btn__type button__blue p-0 m-0">
                        <i className="fas fa-edit" />
                      </button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                      <button className="major__btn__type button__red p-0 m-0 ml-2">
                        <i className="fas fa-trash" />
                      </button>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }): <div> Loading Tests </div> }

      {moreTest && (
        <div className="row">
          <button onClick={showMoreTest} className="btn btn-lightblue w-100">
            {!loadingMore ? <> 
            <i className="fas fa-chevron-down pr-1" />
            Show More
            </> : "Loading..."}
          </button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It wrok but I am looking for how i can improve it.

Comment: No detail is not fetched. Code is not complete. Only Tests is fetched for now.

Comment: Updated the description. Thanks for helping to make the question clear.